# MongoEngine Insert Queries

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I've a model `User`

```
class User(db.DynamicDocument):
    user_id = db.UUIDField(primary_key=True,required=True,default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.StringField(default='')
    phone = db.ListField(db.StringField,default=list)
    gcm_details = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('UserGCM'),default=list)
```

where gcm_details is an `EmbeddedDocumentField` whose details are as follow:-

```
class UserGCM(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    gcm_key = db.StringField(default='')
    device_id = db.StringField(default='')
```

I perform the insert query as follow:-

```
name = 'something'
phone = ['12345678','456789']
gcm_obj = UserGCM(gcm_key=gcm_key,device_id=device_id)

user = User(name=name,push__phone=phone,push__gcm_details=gcm_obj).save()
```

This gets saved. However, when I see the details in the mongo shell, I get the following document.

```
{
    "_id": BinData(3,
    "MjpPJaNTQ823WuA8BP47jQ=="),
    "parent_id": BinData(3,
    "Ig7LNNAVQzCbjYG2KXvQjw=="),
    "name": "something",
    "phone": [

    ],

    "gcm_details": [

    ],

    "push__phone": [
        "9999999999"
    ],
    "push__gcm_details": {
        "gcm_key": "string",
        "device_id": "string",
        "_cls": "UserGCM"
    }
}
```

Notice the empty `phone` and `gcm_details` field, and added `push__phone` and `push__gcm_details` field. How is this happening?

If I do just

```
user = User(name=name,phone=phone,gcm_details=gcm_obj).save()
```

without using `push__`, it throws an error saying:-

```
TypeError: unbound method _validate() must be called with StringField instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)
```

What's going on with this? What wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

> phone = db.ListField(**db.StringField**, default=list)

You should use an instance of the `StringField` like this:

```
phone = db.ListField(db.StringField(), default=list)
```

Then you will be able to do what you want:

```
name = 'something'
phone = ['12345678', '456789']
gcm = UserGCM(gcm_key=gcm_key, device_id=device_id)
user = User(
    name=name,
    phone=phone,
    gcm_details=[gcm],
).save()
```